# Mongoose Models & Integration Testing Race Conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hapi.js

Haven't been able to find any answers to these questions through Twitter or the Mongoose JS Gitter channel and would appreciate some help.

I'm writing an API using a Hapi.JS and Mongoose. I'm using a test database for my integration tests. What I've found though is that if I clear the database after more than one describe block it negatively effects my ability to save and run queries in subsequent describe blocks. I'll leave some annotated code below.

How can I clear the database after each test and not have any race conditions that effect other tests?

```
'use strict'

//this test will pass when run alone
// it clears the db at the end of it's run

let testConfig = require('../fixtures/fixtures.js')
let User = require('../../models/user.js')
let Bucket = require('../../models/bucket.js')
let BucketFactory = require('../../factories/bucket-factory.js')
let request = require('request')
let bluebird = require('bluebird')
let mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = bluebird


describe('Buckets API', function() {

    it('should get all buckets', function(done){
        request.get(`${testConfig.testConfig.testUrl}/buckets`, (err, response, body)=>{
            if (err){ throw new Error(err)}
            expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200)
            done()
        })
    })

    it('should get a bucket by its id', function (done) {
        request.get(`${testConfig.testConfig.testUrl}/buckets/${mongoose.Types.ObjectId()}`, (err, response, body)=>{
            expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200)
            done()
        })
    });

    it('should post it', function (done) {
        let testBucket = {name: "Drill", userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId()}
        request.post(`${testConfig.testConfig.testUrl}/buckets`, {json: testBucket}, (err, response, body)=>{
            if(err){ throw new Error(err)}
            expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(200)
            done()
        } )
    });
    // i dont need this afterEach
    // but for illustrative purposes it will mess up the latter test
    // which will pass if i run it by itself
    // but it shouldnt right?
    afterEach((done)=>{
        Bucket.remove({}).then(()=>{done()})
    })
})

describe('findByAndUpdate', function () {
    beforeEach((done)=>{
        // this factory creates and saves a bucket
        // i've verified this by checking the test database manually
        let newBucket = BucketFactory
        done()
    })
    it('should find and update', function (done) {
        Bucket.find({}).exec()
            .then((data)=>{
                request.put(`${testConfig.testConfig.testUrl}/buckets/${data._id}`, {json: {name: 'Marvel'}}, (err, response, body)=>{
                    if(err){ throw new Error(err)}
                    console.log(body)
                    expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(200)
                    done()
                } )
            })

    });

    afterEach((done)=>{
        Bucket.remove({}).then(()=>{done()})
    })
});
```

Comment: You may want to look at the `mockgoose` npm package, which has a `reset` method that clears the temp database without effecting indexes.

Comment: @BrianShamblen Even in a case such as this, if I have multiple integration tests running wouldn't there still be race conditions happening because multiple files are opening and closing the mockgoose instance asynchronously?

Comment: Tests are run in order within each file, and one file at a time, even with async tests.